# Unclaimed space - dropdown menu CSS in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem with obtaining the effect of the dropdown menu to Wordpress template. I tried already do for many hours and it is unchanged. My knowledge of CSS is not too big, so I ask you for help.

I added to the template function dropdown menu that works on the theme of the child. I would like to get rid of gaps that are unnecessary for items from the sub-menu. Example, I'm interested in the effect as in the case of the "Test 1" and "dropmenu."

Child code:

```
.sub-menu { 
  visibility: hidden; /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: -20px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible; /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  height: 64px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s; /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */

}

.menu-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Image: [explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oxr5.png)

Website: [here link](http://szalcial.ugu.pl/)

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is coming from `.sub-menu`. You have `height: 0;` on `.sub-menu`, which is good, but the margin-top on the `li`'s is overflowing and creating that space.

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.sub-menu` seems to fix it.